# Avoid double execution of keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to create a table that contains two columns and an entry to modify them, the modifier after the first row the function starts to execute twice and make it impossible to write in the second column.

This is the function of the modifier:

```
function mdflv(){
    
    $("#mdfTbl").keyup(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && getData(this)!=''){
            if ($(this).parent().attr('id').split('.')[1].split('_')[1] == '0'){//This means if the position is 0 the position is in the id the number before the _td
                $("#attrTbl").attr('col', '0');
                father = $(this).parent();//Searching the father.
                $("body").append($(this));
                $(this).hide();
                if (exist(getData("attrTbl"), getData($(this))) == false){
                    //If theres no duplicate...
                    td = document.createElement('TD');//Creating the new TD
                    $(td).attr('id', $("#attrTblBd").children().length+'.td_1');//Adding the ID.
                    $(father).parent().append(td);//Appending the td to the grand father AKA: the body of the table.
                    $(father).append(getData($(this).attr('id')));//Appendding the data.
                    $(td).append(this);//Appending the modifier to the new TD
                    $(this).attr('value', '');//Cleaning
                    $(this).focus();//Focus again.
                    $(this).show();
                }else{
                    father.append(this);
                    $(this).show();
                }
                return false;
            }else{
                var newCont = parseInt($("#tbody1").children().length)+1;
                //getting the td that will store the data.
                var father = $(this).parent();
                //Appending the data to the TD.
                $(father).append(getData(this));
                //This going to be the next td  
                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                $(td).attr('id', (newCont)+'_td.0');
                $(td).append(this);
                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                $("#attrTblBd").append(tr);
                $(tr).attr('id', (newCont)+'_tr');
                $(tr).append(td);
                $(this).attr('value', '');//Cleaning
                $(this).show();
                $(this).focus();//Focus again.
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<html><head father="*html" id="header">
        <title father="*head" id="ttl">KarinApp(Karina Application Web Maker)</title>
                <link href="http://www.karinapp.com/favicon.ico" id="favIcon" rel="SHORTCUT ICON">
            <link href="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/css/karinapp-style/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" id="jQueryUI" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link father="*head" href="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/css/main.css" id="general_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT1" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT2" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT3" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT4" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT5" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script> 
        <script id="SCRIPT6" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT8" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT9" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript">\\n<!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT10" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT12" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT12" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT13" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/general.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT14" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/Catcher.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT15" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/loadPage.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT16" language="javascript" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/general/scripts/editor/edit_area_full.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT17" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT18" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/scripts/config.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT19" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/scripts/style.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT20" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script father="*head" id="SCRIPT21" src="http://www.karinapp.com/modules/appgen/scripts/properties.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <script id="SCRIPT22" type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                postLoad();
            }
                        function __init__(){
                                 main();
                        }
        </script>
<script father="*head" id="batuteJS" src="/modules/appgen/scripts/batute.js" type="text/javascript"><!--empty--></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" father="*head" id="test_css" href="http://dev.karinapp.com/modules/test/css/main.css"><script type="text/javascript" id="jQuery-test" srcpath="/modules/general/scripts/jQuery.js"><!--empty--></script><script type="text/javascript" id="gnrlScrpt" srcpath="/modules/general/scripts/general.js"><!--empty--></script><script type="text/javascript" id="ctchScrpt" srcpath="/modules/general/scripts/Catcher.js"><!--empty--></script><script type="text/javascript" id="pdloadScr" srcpath="/modules/general/scripts/loadPage.js"><!--empty--></script><script type="text/javascript" id="pdLoader">window.onload = function(){postLoad();
__init__();}</script></head>
<body id="general_bod" key="53a62b31a99b6142cbc5682741a272d2de823713" style="cursor: auto; ">
<div father="*html" id="body" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; " pathcls="modules/test/css/main.css:#body"><!--empty--></div>
                                <div class="ground_div" father="*body" id="optionsDiv" style="position: fixed; ">
               <button father="@optionsDiv" id="addwdg_inp" state="open" type="button" value="Agregar componente" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Agregar componente</span></button>
               <button father="@optionsDiv" id="addPg_inp" type="button" value="Guardar Pagina" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Guardar Pagina</span></button>
               <button father="@optionsDiv" id="addPD_inp" type="button" value="Crear PostData" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Crear PostData</span></button>
               <button father="@optionsDiv" id="addBT_inp" type="button" value="Crear Instrucciones" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Crear Instrucciones</span></button>
      </div><div style="outline-width: 0px; outline-style: initial; outline-color: initial; width: 250px; position: absolute; display: block; z-index: 1002; left: 104px; top: 64px; height: 400px; " class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-WdgCol"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" unselectable="on"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-WdgCol" unselectable="on">Componentes Basicos</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" unselectable="on"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on">close</span></a></div><div class="properties_div ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" father="*body" id="WdgCol" main="true" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 354px; ">
                <label father="@WdgCol" for="container" id="cnt_lab">Contenedor:</label><select father="@properties_div" id="container"><option father="container" id="1" value="body">Body</option></select>
                <table father="@WdgCol" id="widgetsCol">
            
               <tbody><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.0" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.0.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.0.0.0" tag="a" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">A</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="area" tag="area" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">AREA</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="audio" tag="audio" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Audio</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.3" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.3.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.3.0.0" tag="base" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">BASE</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="0bdo" tag="bdo" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">BDO</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="inp" tag="input" typ="button" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Button)</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.6" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.6.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.6.0.0" tag="button" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Button</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="code" tag="code" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Code</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="col" tag="col" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Column</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.9" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.9.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.9.0.0" tag="colgroup" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Colgroup</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="dl" tag="dl" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">DL</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="div" tag="div" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">DIV</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.12" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.12.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.12.0.0" tag="form" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Form</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="h1" tag="h1" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">H1</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="img" tag="img" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Image</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.15" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.15.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.15.0.0" tag="input" typ="checkbox" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Checkbox)</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="inp" tag="input" typ="file" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(file)</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="inp" tag="input" typ="hidden" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Hidden)</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.18" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.18.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.18.0.0" tag="input" typ="image" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Image)</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="inp" tag="input" typ="radio" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Radio)</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="input" tag="input" typ="text" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Text)</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.21" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.21.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.21.0.0" tag="label" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Label</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="link" tag="link" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Link</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="map" tag="map" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Map</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.24" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.24.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.24.0.0" tag="meta" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Meta</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="obj" tag="object" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Object</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="ol" tag="ol" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">OL</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.27" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.27.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.27.0.0" tag="input" typ="password" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Password)</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="p" tag="p" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">P</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="pre" tag="pre" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">PRE</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.30" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.30.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.30.0.0" tag="input" typ="reset" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(Reset)</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="smp" tag="samp" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Samp</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="srpt" tag="script" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Script</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.33" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.33.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.33.0.0" tag="select" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Select</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="spn" tag="span" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Span</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="stl" tag="style" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Style</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.36" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.36.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.36.0.0" tag="input" typ="submit" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Input(submit)</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="tbl" tag="table" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Table</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="tbody" tag="tbody" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">TBody</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.39" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.39.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.39.0.0" tag="textarea" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">TextArea</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="tfoot" tag="tfoot" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">TFoot</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="thead" tag="thead" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">THead</button></td></tr><tr father="@" id="wDG_bod.0.1.42" mlength="3" tchild="WdgEl">
                         <td father="WdgBodModel" id="wDG_bod.0.1.42.0"><button id="wDG_bod.0.1.42.0.0" tag="ul" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">UL</button></td>
                    <td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="var" tag="var" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Var</button></td><td father="WdgBodModel" id="WdgEl"><button id="video" tag="video" new="true" style="position: relative; " class="ui-draggable">Video</button></td></tr></tbody></table>
               <hr father="@WdgCol" id="hr0">
               <button father="@WdgCol" id="openPal">Abrir Paleta</button>
    </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; " unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1002; " unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1003; " unselectable="on"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1004; " unselectable="on"></div></div><div father="*body" id="btcreator" style="display: block; ">
            <!--Comment-->
            
            <label father="@btcreator" id="fncNm_lbl"><!--empty-->              Name:
            </label>
            <label father="@btcreator" id="fatherlbl"><!--empty-->Father:
            </label>
            <input father="@btcreator" id="fncnm" type="text">
            <select father="@btcreator" id="fatherbt"><!--Comment--><option father="@fatherbt" id="fatherbt_Opt0" name="fatherbt_Opt0" value="none">No father</option></select>
            
            <button father="@btcreator" id="createBt" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><!--empty-->Create</span></button><select father="@btcreator" id="fncName"><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt0" name="fncName_Opt0" value="default">Select one...</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt1" name="fncName_Opt1" value="oper">Operation</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt2" name="fncName_Opt2" value="dirls">List of directories</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt3" name="fncName_Opt3" value="opnfl">Open File</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt4" name="fncName_Opt4" value="delete">Delete File</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt5" name="fncName_Opt5" value="compare">Compare</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt6" name="fncName_Opt6" value="cp">Copy</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt7" name="fncName_Opt7" value="get">Get</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt8" name="fncName_Opt8" value="switch">Switch(If-Else)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt9" name="fncName_Opt9" value="upload">Upload</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt10" name="fncName_Opt10" value="modify">Modify(Elements)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt11" name="fncName_Opt11" value="create">Create(Elements)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt12" name="fncName_Opt12" value="find">Select(SQL)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt13" name="fncName_Opt13" value="insert">Insert(SQL)</option><option father="@fncName" id="fncName_Opt14" name="fncName_Opt14" value="update">Update(SQL)</option></select><button father="@btcreator" id="addRpl" value="Add Reply"><!--empty-->Add Reply</button><label father="@btcreator" id="fncNameLbl"><!--empty-->Function:</label>
            
        <label father="@btcreator" for="dtype" id="dTypelbl">Data-Type:</label><select father="@btcreator" id="dtype"><!--Comment--><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt0" name="dtype_Opt0" value="data">Data</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt1" name="dtype_Opt1" value="int">Integer</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt2" name="dtype_Opt2" value="float">Float</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt3" name="dtype_Opt3" value="str">String</option><option father="@dtype" id="dtype_Opt4" name="dtype_Opt4" value="list">Array/List</option></select><button father="@btcreator" id="goto">Go to object...</button><button father="@btcreator" id="frmbt">Add from batute</button><button father="@btcreator" id="addfrmsrc">Add from source</button><button father="@btcreator" id="prevsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="gtson" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="nxtsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="fthsb" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title=""><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span></button><button father="@btcreator" id="svBt" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Save object</span></button><div father="@btcreator" id="btattr"><!--Comment--><table border="1" father="btattr" id="attrTbl" width="100%" col="0"><thead father="@attrTbl" id="attrTblHead"><tr>
<th>Property
</th><th>Value
</th></tr></thead><tbody father="@attrTbl" id="attrTblBd"><tr id="tbody0"><td id="tbody.tr_0">adsfasdfadfasdf</td><td id="1.td_1">adsfasdfasdfasf</td></tr>                                             <tr id="1_tr"><td id="1_td.0">adsfasdfasdfdf</td></tr><tr id="1_tr"><td id="1_td.0"><input id="mdfTbl" style="width: 180px; display: inline-block; " type="text"></td></tr></tbody><colgroup><col father="@attrTbl" id="col0" width="50%"><col father="@attrTbl" id="col1" width="50%"></colgroup></table></div></div><button father="*body" id="showhid" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="" style="left: 502px; "><span class="ui-button-text"><!--Comment--></span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"></span></button></body></html>
```

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Can explain a bit better what is happening? What is "the modifier" (what kind of element) and where is the event handler bound to.

Comment: The modifier is the input:text that takes the information and appended into the TD on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't attached your relevant markup.
But I'm guessing the event is [**bubbling**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) up from its source.

You might want to recheck where the handlers are attached to 
and if required prevent bubbling up by using `e.stopPropogation()`

or the crude `return false;` within your handler.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem - I did a walkaround using a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var handledCount = 0;

    $("#imageUrl").keyup(function () {
        if (handledCount == 0)
        {
            //method logic
            handled = true;
        }
        handledCount++;
        if (handledCount == 2)
            handledCount = 0;
        return false;
    });
```